# solaris + vxprint + mirror for rootvol & rootdisk7vol not exist

Tags: solaris, mirror, disk-volume, veritas-cluster-server

I run the vxprint -g rootdg
on my Solaris machine (HW- NETRA T2000)

As we see here - rootvol & rootdisk7vol has missing lines (swapvol is OK)

How to fix the rootvol & rootdisk7vol in order to bring the missing lines as we see then in swapvol ?

```
  vxprint -g rootdg
  TY NAME         ASSOC        KSTATE   LENGTH   PLOFFS   STATE    TUTIL0  PUTIL0
  dg rootdg       rootdg       -        -        -        -        -       -

  dm rootdisk     c0t1d0s2     -        286617216 -       -        -       -
  dm rootmirror   c0t3d0s2     -        286617216 -       -        -       -

  v  rootdisk7vol gen          ENABLED  122112   -        ACTIVE   -       -
  pl rootdisk7vol-01 rootdisk7vol ENABLED 122112 -        ACTIVE   -       -
  sd rootdisk-03  rootdisk7vol-01 ENABLED 122112 0        -        -       -


  v  rootvol      root         ENABLED  253016064 -       ACTIVE   -       -
  pl rootvol-01   rootvol      ENABLED  253016064 -       ACTIVE   -       -
  sd rootdisk-02  rootvol-01   ENABLED  253016064 0       -        -       -


  v  swapvol      swap         ENABLED  33479040 -        ACTIVE   -       -
  pl swapvol-01   swapvol      ENABLED  33479040 -        ACTIVE   -       -
  sd rootdisk-01  swapvol-01   ENABLED  33479040 0        -        -       -
  pl swapvol-02   swapvol      ENABLED  33479040 -        ACTIVE   -       -
  sd rootmirror-01 swapvol-02  ENABLED  33479040 0        -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "missing lines"?

From the output provided it appears that you have multiple plesks for the swapvol volume, but only a single plesk for rootvol and rootdisk7vol.

What exactly is not working? It is unclear what you are trying to achieve here.